# Do I need the registry defined in .npmrc file when I have the publishConfig defined in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

I have the `publishConfig` defined in the `package.json` to publish to a private repository. Do I need the `.npmrc` file with custom registry as well for publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe no. As per the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc.html), *npmrc* has no effect when you publish your repository.

Comment: One of the .npmrc registry entries may be used if publishConfig does not specify a registry and the registry is not overridden on the command line.

Comment: I've tested npm version 6.14.15 and it reads registry settings from .npmrc during publish.